# How to solve comparing two functions easily

Tags: functions

Let two function be f(x) and g(x).

Now , let f(x-1) = g(x).

Then , Q 1 is find the value of g($\frac{x+1}{2}$) in terms of f(x)?

Q 2 Find value of f(x-3)+4 in terms of g(x).

Problem I am getting is that I am not able to understand how to solve these.

Like for 1st one. Answer in my book is that it would be f(x+1/2 -1). Why is it like this ?.

Like I got confused for this solution here since for another Q , to value of g(x) in terms of f(2x-1) was asked .Answer was g(2x). Now , here I thought maybe we just have to multiple x of f into g. But it gets different for 1st one. Please help in how should I solve the steps.

Comment: $g(x)=f(x-1)$ so $g(5)=f(5-1)$ and $g(42)=f(42-1)$ and $g(y)=f(y-1)$ and $g(x^3)=f(x^3-1)$.  Whatever is plugged into $g$, we can say the result is equal to that same thing, however complicated or simple, after having subtracted $1$ from it and plugging it into $f$..., even if that thing happened to have been written involving an $x$.  So $g(\frac{x+1}{2}) = f(\frac{x+1}{2}-1)$

Comment: Similarly, we could just as easily have said $g(x+1)=f((x+1)-1)$ or more simply $f(x)=g(x+1)$ and done the same.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks a lot. I got the idea here. One last Q , if f(2x-2) is given . Then , how should be solve. I did is f(2(x-1)). So , it will be g(2x). Is this correct ?

Comment: So, since $f(\heartsuit) = g(\heartsuit + 1)$, whatever $\heartsuit$ was... however complicated or simple... replacing $\heartsuit$ with $2x-2$......

Comment: @JMoravitz  So , it should be g(2x-1)

Comment: Yes.  Don't overzealously try to factor where inappropriate and recognize that in general a function $F$ might not satisfy $F(x+1)=F(x)+1$.  If you are asked to add one to the final result of $2(x-1)$ that is just $(2(x-1))+1$.  We are adding $1$ to the outside and that is not the same thing as adding $1$ to the inside.

Comment: Hmm. Ohk. @JMoravitz Sir. Thanks a lot. I was struggling over this for long time now. Yo usage made it much easier now.

Comment: @JMoravitz Is this possible f(2x-2) = f(2(x-1)) ?

Comment: Yes, certainly.  It isn't necessary however.  Note that $2x-2 = 2(x-1)$.  Just like how $(2x-2)+1 = (2(x-1))+1$ and so on... it wasn't hurtful to rewrite as that, but it wasn't helpful in this situation either... so whether you wrote $f(2x-2)=g((2x-2)+1)$ or if you wrote $f(2(x-1))=g((2(x-1))+1)$ or otherwise, it doesn't really matter... do whatever is more comfortable to you.

Comment: Ok. Sure. Thanks a lot. Have a good day, How can I accept your answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve Q1, just say f(y-1)=g(y) by the problem given, then substitute y=(x+1)/2 to get g($\frac{x+1}{2}$)=f($\frac{x+1}{2}-1$)=f($\frac{x-1}{2}$).

You can solve Q2 similarly by saying f(y-1)=g(y) again but this time substituting y=x-2 to get f(x-3)=g(x-2), then add 4 to both sides to get f(x-3)+4=g(x-2)+4.

However, notice that **this method of substituting y=f(x) where f(x) is some expression in terms of x** (for example, for Q1 f(x)=(x+1)/2) **only works when f(x) is a a bijection, or one-to-one function.**

If you don't know what a one-to-one function is, it is when every value of x matches up with exactly one value of f(x), and every value of f(x) matches up with exactly one value of x. For example, f(x)=x-8 is a one-to-one function because we can solve for x in terms of f(x): x=f(x)+8 but f(x)=x^2-8 is not because when we solve for x in terms of f(x) we don't get a single solution: x=±$\sqrt{f(x)+8}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple, just assume-
$$\frac{x+1}{2}=m$$
So $$g(m)=f(m-1)$$
Now just put the value of m in there-
$$g\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)=f\left(\frac{x+1}{2}-1\right)$$
Now for the second part-
$$f(x-3)=g(x-2)$$
Now add 4 to both sides-
$$f(x-3)+4=g(x-2)+4$$
Hope it helps.